# Solving $\frac{(\sqrt{x} - \sqrt{a})^{2}}{a x} \cdot \log\left(x + a + n\right) = \psi$ for $x$

Tags: logarithms, roots

Consider the following equation in $\mathbb{R}$:

$$\frac{\left(\sqrt{x} - \sqrt{a}\right)^{2}}{ax} \cdot \log\left(x + a + n\right) = \psi$$

for $x$, $a$, $n$ and $\psi$ strictly positive, and where $\log$ is the natural logarithm.

Is there a name for this type of equation? And would there be a way to solve it for $x$?

Comment: I'm quite sure this will require numerical methods. Perhaps it can be solved somehow with Lambert's $W$ function. It might help if you edit the question to tell us where the equation comes from.

Comment: Lambert W function doesn’t help. Just tried.